# Url Redirection in Classic Asp page

Tags: asp-classic, redirect, http-status-code-302

I have a issue related to redirection

I want to apply redirection if someone uses `http://mywebsite.com/` then the URL would be redirected to `http://www.mywebsite.com/`.  I know it is a 302 redirection but I dont know how to apply it in coding ........ what VBScript could be used for applying redirection ??

My website is build in Classic ASP and VBScript ... any piece of code would be better for me

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")` to get the host part so that you can check if it starts with `www.` or not.

If it doesn't then just issue a `Response.Redirect()` to the appropriate URL since it'll do a 302 for you:

e.g.

```
If Left(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"), 4) <> "www." Then
  Dim newUri
  'Build the redirect URI by prepending http://www. to the actual HTTP_HOST
  'and adding in the URL (i.e. the page the user requested)
  newUri = "http://www." & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") & Request.ServerVariables("URL")

  'If there were any Querystring arguments pass them through as well
  If Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING") <> "" Then
    newUri = newUri & "?" & Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")
  End If

  'Finally make the redirect
  Response.Redirect(newUri)
End If
```

The above does a redirect ensuring the requested page and querystring are preserved

Comment: Using this code from RobV with the 302 redirect which I posted in my answer would be the complete solution.

Comment: @Randam `Response.Redirect()` does a 302 anyway so no need to manually set the status code and headers - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Response.Status = "302 Moved Temporary"
Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://www.mywebsite.com/"
```

Comment: but to apply this solution, isnt there some checks to be applied like @Robv did ... ` If Left(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"), 4) <> "www." Then Response.Status = "302 Moved Temporary" Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://www.mywebsite.com/" end if ` and with the @Robv code i could also preserve querystrings too ...

Comment: What would be the point of preserving the QueryString but not the Path/ScriptName?